# PHP: ifelse PHP function issues

Tags: php, arrays, post, if-statement

I'm having trouble getting some PHP code to work.

Here is the function:

```
function getCellColor($dow) {
    if (isset($_POST[$dow.alternative])) {
        return "style=\"background: yellow; color:#fff;\""; 
    }
    /*elseif (isset($_POST[$dow.shifthours]) && ($_POST[$dow.shifthours] == "OFF")) {
        return "style=\"background: red; color:#fff;\"";
    }*/
    if ($_POST[$dow.shifthours] == "OFF") {
            return "style=\"background: red; color:#fff;\"";
    }
    else {
        return "style=\"background: green; color:#fff;\"";
    }
}
```

Here is the section that outputs to the browser:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo preTableFrmt();
    foreach($engineer as $a => $b) {
        echo "| [[$engineer[$a]]] || ".getCellColor('mon')." | $monday[$a] || ".getCellColor('tues')." | $tuesday[$a] || ".getCellColor('wed')." | $wednesday[$a] || ".getCellColor('thur')." | $thursday[$a] || ".getCellColor('fri')." | $friday[$a] || ".getCellColor('sat')." | $saturday[$a] || ".getCellColor('sun')." | $sunday[$a] <br />";
    }
    echo postTableFrmt();
}
else { echo "Waiting for data..."; }
```

The "Alternative" part is working.  If it is checked, it overrides everything and does the "yellow" background.

The part that doesn't is when I leave the "Alternative" unchecked (default) and the drop down then is set to OFF (a form option from the drop down), it returns the "green" background.  If I set it to another option (not OFF), it still goes to "green" background.  The background needs to be red if set to OFF and anything else it should be "green".

Form Example HTML:

```
<select name="tuesshifthours[]" id="tuesshifthours">
    <optgroup label="Select Shift Time">
        <option value="OFF">OFF</option>
        <option value="8am5pm">8AM-5PM</option>
        <option value="7am7pm">7AM-7PM</option>
      <option value="7pm7am">7PM-7AM</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
  <label for="tuesalternative">A?</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="tuesalternative[]" id="tuesalternative" value="on" />
```

Additionally, here is my $_POST data (returns green background):

```
["monshifthours"]=>
  array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "OFF"
}
```

$_POST data (also returns green background):

```
["monshifthours"]=>
  array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "7am7pm"
}
```

Comment: This: `$_POST[$dow.alternative]` is invalid PHP syntax, or at least it probably doesn't do what you think it does. What *should* this do?

Comment: @deceze - It's using magic strings to turn it `'mon'` in `$dow` into `'monalternative'`. It should be `$dow . 'alternative'` to avoid a PHP notice. Same for `$dow . 'shifthours'`.

Comment: Well it works for that one, but not the other ones, so it seems to work.  `$dow` comes from the calling of the function, so that you can call it by `getCellColor("mon")` or `getCellColor("tues")`, that way I can reuse the code.  The HTML dropdown names are named `monshifthours` (all the way to sunday) and `monalternative` (all the way to sunday). I've updated my question with a sample of the dropdown/checkbox that is on my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your post variables are arrays and not strings. Try this:

```
if ($_POST[$dow . 'shifthours'][0] == "OFF") { ... }
```

Comment: This was the fix; appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Very hard code... Try to clear your brain and write easy :)

So. $_POST[$dow.'shifthours'] cat not be equal "OFF", because it contains sub array.

Right way:

```
$_POST[$dow.'shifthours'][0] == "OFF"
```